# atoi() keeps returning a 0

Tags: c++, pointers, user-input, atoi

In the code I've written, I take in a string, check if it contains only decimal digits, then convert the string to an int. However, in my code, `atoi` returns a 0, not the string as an `int`. Can someone tell me where I am messing up?

```
while (!sucess || 0 == Entries){
  delete [] bufferptr;
  buffer = nullptr;
  buffer = new char [MAX];
  bufferptr = buffer;

  cin.getline(buffer, MAX, '\n');


  while (*buffer){
    if (isdigit(*buffer++)){
      success = true;
    } else {
      success = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (success){
    numEntries = atoi(buffer);
    cout << endl << numEntries << endl;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do some debugging, will you? Stack Overflow is not a human-powered cloud debugging service.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that with `isdigit(*buffer++)` you first call `isdigit` with value of `*buffer` and then increments the pointer by one.

`if (isdigit(*buffer++))`

With this line you are already at the character *after* the digit.

So you should increment when you don't succeed, and break when you succeed.

... and as the comment suggest, try to do some debugging by yourself. Your bug is not really hard to debug, even with some `cout` and without a debugger and so (try inserting a `cout << buffer << endl` in you while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extraction operator to parse the stream content directly into an `int`:

```
std::cin >> numEntries;
```

For error checking, read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2.